# django-sitetree 0.7 sitetreedump not working

Tags: django, django-templates, django-sitetree

I am using [django-sitetree](https://github.com/idlesign/django-sitetree) on a Django project.  It is working fine so far in my templates.  When I try to:

```
python manage.py sitetreedump > treedump.json
```

I get an unknown command error back.  I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: I installed django-sitetree via pip and got version 0.7.  When I look in the installed site package, I don't see any management directory -- which is where I believe django-admin commands are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Using pip to install django-sitetree doesn't include the django-admin management commands.  Not sure why.  Installing directly from the git repository as a submodule in my project works.